# How to call an external Api for prayer timings from SharePoint OnPremise(2019)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, api

I want PrayerTimings API to be called on Page load. I am using SharePoint 2019. When I use the API inside the server is not getting called. I am injecting the 'Prayertime.js' file using my SPFx Extension. Outside server it is working. Is there a way to get this data?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser developer console? If Yes, please share it in your question.

Comment: Hi Dikesh, No errors. It is working fine outside server.